# Magento2 data-migration-tool Integrity check failed

Tags: magento2

I migrated magento from 1.7.0.1 to 2.0, but I have encountered the following error:

The first time prompt:
[image]

Then I ignore it by map.xml file.

The second time prompt:
[image]

But the same prompt: **Integrity check failed**

Please help me!

Answer (score 3):

Here's the code I added temporarly to vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/Mode/AbstractMode.php at line 82 to locate which step failed :

```
if (!$result) {
    $this->logger->info(
        'failed',
        ['step' => $step, 'stage' => $stage, 'mode' => $this->mode]
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue on php 5.5.9 and after debugging, I noticed that the order of columns for table core_url_rewrite was different from the one described in the file
 vendors/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/Step/UrlRewrite/Version191to2000.php at line 76 :

```
/**
 * Expected table structure
 * @var array
 */
protected $structure = [
    MapInterface::TYPE_SOURCE => [
        'core_url_rewrite' => [
            'url_rewrite_id' ,
            'store_id',
            'id_path',
            'request_path',
            'target_path',
            'is_system',
            'options',
            'description',
            'category_id',
            'product_id',
        ],
    ],
    MapInterface::TYPE_DEST => [
        'url_rewrite' => [
            'url_rewrite_id',
            'entity_type',
            'entity_id',
            'request_path',
            'target_path',
            'redirect_type',
            'store_id',
            'description',
            'is_autogenerated',
            'metadata'
        ],
    ]
];
```

Do your columns in core_url_rewrite are ordered exactly like the following ?

```
url_rewrite_id, store_id, id_path, request_path, target_path, is_system, options, description, category_id, product_id
```

If not try changing the order and it should work.

Comment: My columns is the same.

Comment: You can see on the next answer how I found which step failed

Comment: One more option is - this tool also checks if the length of URL Rewrite tables in source and destination are not equal. For example I got migration error on url rewrite step - source length = 27556, and destination's - 27553. You can put a log in data-migration-tool\src\Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000::volume(). Here where I found the issue http://oyenetwork.com/articles/data-migration-to-magento2-case-study/

Answer (score 0):

You can debug your step using modify file in,

```
//vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/Mode/AbstractMode.php


protected function runStage($object, $step, $stage)
    {
        $this->logger->info(
            'started',
            ['step' => $step, 'stage' => $stage, 'mode' => $this->mode]
        );
        if ($this->progress->isCompleted($object, $stage)) {
            return true;
        }
        try {
            $result = $object->perform();
        } catch (\Migration\Exception $e) {
            if (!$result) {
                $this->logger->info(
                    'failed',
                    ['step' => $step, 'stage' => $stage, 'mode' => $this->mode]
                );
            }
            $this->logger->error($e->getMessage());
            return false;
        }

        if ($result && $this->canBeCompleted) {
            $this->progress->saveResult($object, $stage, $result);
        }        

        if (!$result) {
                $this->logger->info(
                    'failed Step',
                    ['step' => $step, 'stage' => $stage, 'mode' => $this->mode]
                );
            }
        return $result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i had arrived issue for integrity check failed for magento 1.9.2.1 version to magento 2.
issue are solved using core_url_rewrite table column sort order.

**core_url_rewrte table must have below snapshot like field sort order and issue are solved.**
[image]